# Reuse ASP.NET MVC 5 session cookie in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses a custom authentication scheme and sessions for storing state using `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie.

Now there is a requirement to put a React front-end in front of an ASP.NET Core Web API. There is an opportunity to reuse some of the service code from the API. The showstopper is the authentication.

Is it possible to reuse/share the existing cookie and authentication scheme from a React web application? JWT and IdentityServer appear to be solid options but would require a significant rewrite to the existing system.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want to share authentication cookies between ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core apps, you need to rebuild the asp.net core cookie authentication.

Since the asp.net core and asp.net use different way to encrypt the authentication cookie, so you should let them use the same way to encrypt the cookie  to get the token work for both asp.net and asp.net core application and make sure there are in the same domain.

More details about how to set the application to share cookie between ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core apps I suggest you could refer to this MSFT [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps).

Some part of the document:

> ASP.NET 4.x apps that use Katana Cookie Authentication Middleware can be configured to generate authentication cookies that are compatible with the ASP.NET Core Cookie Authentication Middleware. This allows upgrading a large site's individual apps in several steps while providing a smooth SSO experience across the site.

> When an app uses Katana Cookie Authentication Middleware, it calls UseCookieAuthentication in the project's Startup.Auth.cs file. ASP.NET 4.x web app projects created with Visual Studio 2013 and later use the Katana Cookie Authentication Middleware by default. Although UseCookieAuthentication is obsolete and unsupported for ASP.NET Core apps, calling UseCookieAuthentication in an ASP.NET 4.x app that uses Katana Cookie Authentication Middleware is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Katana Cookie Authentication can be used to reuse cookie among app. For more detail please find the documentation for [Share Authentication Cookie among app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)